# Application of Cesaro lemma

Tags: probability, convergence-divergence, martingales, cesaro-summable

I would like to show that the sequence of random variables $\frac{S_n}{n}$ defined below converges to zero. The proof requires the application of Cesaro lemma and I don't understand how.

First, let the sequence $M_n$ be an $L^2$-bounded martingale. By the martingale convergence theorem, $M_n$ converges almost surely.

Second, let $S_n$ be a sequence of random variables such that

$$
S_n = \sum_{k=1}^n k(M_k-M_{k-1}) \\
 =\sum_{k=1}^n kM_k - \sum_{k=1}^n kM_{k-1} \\
 = \sum_{k=0}^n kM_k- \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} (k+1)M_k   \\
  = nM_n - \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} M_k$$
where $M_0=0$.

Claim: by Cesaro lemma, $\frac{S_n}{n}$ converges to zero.

Question: Could you help me understand how I can apply Cesaro lemma to show the claim? I found this statement of the Cesaro **theorem** on [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stolz%E2%80%93Ces%C3%A0ro_theorem). Based on it, I would set $b_n\equiv n$ and $a_n\equiv S_n$. However, I don't see how $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \frac{S_{n+1}-S_n}{n+1-n}=\ell$,   which is required by the theorem, where
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \frac{S_{n+1}-S_n}{n+1-n}=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}  S_{n+1}-S_n = (n+1)M_{n+1}-\sum_{k=0}^n M_k - nM_n+\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} M_k=(n+1)M_{n+1}-(n+1)M_n=(n+1)(M_{n+1}-M_n).
$$ I have also found a statement of Cesaro **lemma** on [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1814904/ces%C3%A0ros-lemma-precise-definition-of-limit-indices) forum but, again, I am unable to map $b_n$ and $\nu_n$ to my setting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need the [particular case of arithmetic mean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stolz%E2%80%93Ces%C3%A0ro_theorem#Arithmetic_mean) of Cesàro's lemma, which yields that $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}M_k$ converges almost surely as $n\to+\infty$ to the same limit as that of $M_n$. Hence
$$
\frac{S_n}{n}=M_n-\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}M_k
$$
vanishes almost surely as $n$ goes to infinity.

Comment: Thanks. However, $$
\frac{S_n}{n}=M_n-\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}M_k
$$ i.e., the sum of the second component is up to $n-1$. Does the result still apply?

Comment: Of course. If $u_n$ converges to $l$ as $n\to+\infty$, so does $u_{n-1}$. And if you want to divide by $n-1$ just multiply everything by $n/(n-1)$, which converges to 1.